# Python Eval: What's wrong with this code?

Tags: python, eval, syntax-error

I'm trying to write a very simple Python utility for personal use that counts the number of lines in a text file for which a predicate specified at the command line is true.  Here's the code:

```
import sys

pred = sys.argv[2]
if sys.argv[1] == "stdin" :
    handle = sys.stdin
else :
    handle = open(sys.argv[1])
result = 0
for line in handle :
    eval('result += 1 if ' + pred + ' else 0')
print result
```

When I run it using `python count.py myFile.txt "int(line) == 0"`, I get the following error:

```
  File "c:/pycode/count.py", line 10, in <module>
    eval('toAdd = 1 if ' + pred + ' else 0')
  File "<string>", line 1
    toAdd = 1 if int(line) == 0 else 0
```

This looks like perfectly valid Python code to me (though I've never used Python's eval before, so I don't know what its quirks, if any, are).  Please tell me how I can fix this to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput, sys

pred = eval('lambda line: ' + sys.argv[1])
print sum(1 for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[2:]) if pred(line))
```

Usage: `pywc.py predicate [FILE]...`
Print number of lines that satisfy `predicate` for given `FILE`(s).
With no `FILE`, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Comment: This is excellent, a great improvement over the other versions in simplicity and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks.  This is a heck of a lot faster than the other versions, I guess because the interpreter parses and compiles the predicate O(1) instead of O(N) times.

Answer (score 11):

Try using exec instead of eval.  The difference between the 2 is explained [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/g2swap/byteofpython/read/exec-statement.html)

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
for line in handle:
  result += 1 if eval(pred) else 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The python eval() function evaluates expressions, not statements.  Try replacing the eval() line with:

```
result += eval(pred + " else 0")
```

Comment: `eval('int(line) == 0 else 0')` produces `SyntaxError`.

Answer (score 0):

Really, you are looking for the compile function:

```
>> a = compile("toAdd = 1 if int('0') == 0 else 0", 'tmp2.py', 'exec')
>>> eval(a)
>>> toAdd
1
```

eval is intended only for expressions... compile while compile sequence of statements into a codeblock that can then be eval'ed.